# Post checkbox value/send by email

Tags: javascript, php

in my form, I have a checkbox that I use to calculate some prices. 
I'm using a javascript to perform this action. Here it is:

```
function totalIt() {
  var input = document.getElementsByName("product[]");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(input[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = "€" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

This is the radio:

```
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="10 movie" onclick="totalIt()" /> MOVIE (16.20€)
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="15 sport" onclick="totalIt()" /> SPORT (15.20€)
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="15 soccer" onclick="totalIt()" /> SOCCER (15.20€)
              </label>
            </div>
```

And here we have the field that displays the final prize:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Totale</label>
          <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eur"></i></span>
              <input name="total" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="€" id="total" disabled />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Now, I have a problem to post these variables through a PHP script, that uses PHP mailer class. It cannot display multiple choices as a list! My goal is to:
1- display in the field to the total price, based on value (number)
2- send the form to a mail address, based on value (text, the number is optional if the receiving sees the number is still ok)

Here's my script (php using PHPMailer):

```
$product = isset($_POST['product']) ? $_POST['product'] : array();
foreach ($product as $prodotti_temp){
    $prodotti = $prodotti_temp . "<br />";
}

$message_to_send = "HERE WE HAVE OUR CHECKBOX CHOICES: $prodotti"
```

Unfortunately, something's wrong, and in my mail instead of the right list, I can't see anything but "array" or a blank space, or the last value that was checked (I did multiple attempts).
The price in the field is displayed right, though.
Where's my error?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, for one, you are overwriting the value of `$prodotti` each time through your loop instead of appending/concatenating.

Comment: While you're using PHPMailer, it doesn't really have anything to do with your question.

Comment: Look PHP append https://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.append.php